# Drop down list with data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to create a drop down list that has services from a database table called services. The drop down list appears along with the submit button but none of the three options from my table are showing up.

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Search Services</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name ="searchform" method="post" action="search.php">

    <?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "eric",
    "password", "ebeichner")
    or die("Cannot connect to database:" . 
    mysqli_connect_error($conn));

    echo "<select service= 'service'>";
    echo '<option value="">'.'Please Select Service'.'</option>';
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT service FROM services");

    $query_display = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM services");

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "option value='". $row['service']."'>".$row['service']
        .'</option>';

        }

        echo '</select>';

        ?> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>

        </body>
        <html>
```

Comment: `echo '<option value="'.$row['service'].'">'.$row['service'].'</option>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a '<'

```
echo "<option value='" . $row['service']. "'>" . $row['service'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much I can't believe I missed that!

Comment: Watching your own code can make you blind to such small mistakes ^^ Happens for everyone i guess :)